# OnInitializedAsync vs OnParametersSetAsync

Tags: blazor

I understand the difference between them.

OnInitializedAsync fires once when the component is Initialized where as OnParametersSetAsync fires each time the components parameter is set/changed.

does it mean that in the .razor page we can omit OnInitializedAsync function and do all the coding in this OnParametersSetAsync() function?

does it mean OnInitializedAsync() is redundant?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's say you have a component that makes a call to an API to retrieve some data. It also accepts a parameter called `SortDirection` and you want to sort the data ascending or descending according to its value. The API call should only happen one time, once you have the data in memory you don't need to call the backend anymore. On the other hand let's say the user has a toggle button that changes the sort direction so the `SortDirection` parameter can change multiple times during the component lifecycle. You want to retrieve the data inside `OnInitializedAsync()` but you should apply the sorting inside `OnParametersSetAsync()`. Example:

```
@if (_sortedData != null)
{
    foreach (var item in _sortedData)
    {
        <p>@item</p>
    }
}

@code {
    private List<string>? _data;
    private List<string>? _sortedData;
    private string? _sortDirection;

    [Parameter]
    public string? SortDirection { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _data = await MyService.LoadData();        
    }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        if (_sortDirection != SortDirection)
        {
            _sortDirection = SortDirection;

            if (_sortDirection == "asc")
            {
                _sortedData = _data?.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
            }
            else if (_sortDirection == "desc")
            {
                _sortedData = _data?.OrderByDescending(x => x).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                _sortedData = _data;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this is only an example, but in the example you're likely to do a lot more sorts than necessary if you sort every time the component renders.

Comment: Hi, in the example I'm sorting every time the parameters change (`OnParametersSet`). So it will only sort when the `SortDirection` parameter changes. Am I missing something?

Comment: Added an extra check to see if the sort direction value actually changed based on the pattern described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54347893/10839134

Comment: Depending on your design, `SetParametersAsync` (which calls `OnParametersSet`) will be called more often than you think, thus my comment.  The sort check you added resolves that problem.

Comment: However, unless everything is in the same component, there is no direct link between an event (a click on a sort button to select direction and/or a click on a header column to select the sort column), and the renderer deciding that a parameter has changed on the component and calling `SetParametersAsync`.  It works, but not by design.  See my answer to this recent question which shows how to use events to drive the updates.

Answer (score 5):

`ComponentBase` is just a tool.  It's one implementation of `IComponent`.  99.9% of the world uses it, but it's not compulsory.

You're using a one size fits all swiss army knife component implementation for all your diverse component needs.  There will be redundancy, normally lots of it!  `ComponentBase` is your toolbox, not one of the tools in the box.

`ONinitialized{Async}`/`OnParametersSet{Async}` may be a bit of overkill for many implementations, but so is a lot of the code in `ComponentBase`.

This bit of code gets run on every render, yet 99.x% of the time does absolutely nothing but waste CPU cycles!

```cs
    Task IHandleAfterRender.OnAfterRenderAsync()
    {
        var firstRender = !_hasCalledOnAfterRender;
        _hasCalledOnAfterRender |= true;

        OnAfterRender(firstRender);

        return OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
 }
```

You can see the full implmentation here - https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Components/Components/src/ComponentBase.cs

Also see one of my answers to this question that demonstrates a different more minimalist base component -  [In Blazor, is there any way to get render time for any component without its children?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73717873/in-blazor-is-there-any-way-to-get-render-time-for-any-component-without-its-chi/73788324#73788324)